# C# - Allow Inheritance but Forbid Direct Use of Constructor

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor, proxy-pattern, realproxy

I want to allow inheritance, but forbid the direct construction of any of the inherited classes. Instead, I want to force the usage of the custom method `New()`.

The goal is to make sure that every instance of inherited classes is a transparent proxy of itself.

In this case, it's not possible to make the constructor `private` or `internal`. Otherwise, you can't inherit from the class anymore outside of the assembly.

Is there any elegant way to solve that? My current solution:

```cs
public abstract class Class<This> : MarshalByRefObject where This : Class<This>
{
    private static bool ShouldThrowOnConstruction = true;
    private static readonly object Lock = new object();

    public static This New()
    {
        lock (Lock)
        {
            ShouldThrowOnConstruction = false;
            var instance = (This)new ClassProxy<This>().GetTransparentProxy();
            ShouldThrowOnConstruction = true;
        }
        return instance;
    }

    protected Class()
    {
        if (ShouldThrowOnConstruction)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Direct use of the constructor is forbidden. Use New() instead.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just call `New()` from the consructor?  Am I missing something?

Comment: Isn't it just possible to make the constructor private? Or is that only possible in Java?

Comment: You could make the constructors private and call them within the `New` method.

Comment: @Martin Calling `New()` inside the constructor would still return the original object instead of the proxy.

Comment: @Peterdk @Halhex I've addressed your questions with the latest edit: In this case, it's not possible to make the constructor `private` or `internal`. Otherwise, you can't inherit from the class anymore outside of the assembly.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use a static factory function instead of a constructor?

e.g.

```
public abstract class Class<This> : MarshalByRefObject where This : Class<This>
{
    public static Class<This> Build()
    {
        var instance = (This)new ClassProxy<This>().GetTransparentProxy();
    }

    protected Class() 
    {        
    }
}
```

That's extremely difficult to misuse, and doesn't have the same race condition problems that you required the thread locking for.

I suppose this means that all subclasses would also need to make their default constructor private.  Is that outside your control?

Edit:

In the case you want to guarantee it can't be called, make the constructor throw an exception `throw new InvalidOperationException("Direct use of the constructor is forbidden. Use Build() instead.");`, and your `GetTransparentProxy` method shouldn't call `new` to construct the object but instead use `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject()` to bypass the constructor.  That should allow the instance to be created, but it has a bit of a code smell.

Something like this:

```
public abstract class Class<This> : MarshalByRefObject where This : Class<This>
{
    public static Class<This> Build()
    {
        // Ensure GetTransparentProxy() calls FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject() to create the object, rather than calling `new`
        var instance = (This)new ClassProxy<This>().GetTransparentProxy();
    }

    protected Class() 
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Direct use of the constructor is forbidden. Use Build() instead.");
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't allow inheritance anymore: 'Class<InheritedClass>.Class()' is inaccessible due to its protection level (CS0122)

Comment: Yeah, forgot to make the constructor `protected` vs `private`.  Edited to reflect that.  Thanks :)

Comment: Now the user of the API can still do it wrong and construct its derived class.